# Mismatched GTX560Ti SLI

Tags: windows-7, nvidia-geforce, sli

I can't find ANY information on the internet about this. I have 2 EVGA GTX560Ti models, 1 of them is the 1gb variation, and the other is the 2gb variation (with slightly lower clock speeds).

Is it possible to run them in SLI? I know that wisdom dictates it should be impossible as they are not IDENTICAL models, but i'm hoping that because they are pretty much matched in every other way, it could work.

I'm not that familiar with how SLI scaling works these days, as I have not run an SLI setup since I ran two 6800's!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, you can.** The faster card will clock down to the speed of the slower card, and the card with 2GB of memory will only be able to use 1GB of it. Otherwise, they should run in SLI just fine.

The only major requirement these days is that the processor is the same (GTX560Ti), and then the driver scales the cards back to the lowest common denominator to make them compatible (slowest clock speed, least amount of memory).

Comment: Excellent news. They have plenty of room for overclocking so i should be able to get them back up to speed (or slightly over). Thanks for your answer!

Comment: According to a forum thread at NVidia "Note: It used to be possible to enable SLI on cards with differing VRAM (EG 8800GTS 640 and 320) via the 'coolbits' mod. However, this mod will not work with newer cards or newer drivers." http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=172243

Comment: @BonGart [The official FAQ](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/technology/sli/faq#c19) still lists CoolBits as allowing differing VRAM amounts, and my personal experience has included a GTX580 1.5GB and a GTX580 3GB working just fine in SLI. I think there was a period of time when it didn't work, but that was merely a software limit, and they improved the drivers to allow for differences.